# What is the best way to avoid callback pyramid in c++11?

Tags: c++11

I am learning asynchronous programming, and quite often I find myself writing code like:

```
fooAsync(input, [=](Output output) {
  // ...
  asyncA(output, [=](OutputA outputA) {
    // ...
    asyncB(outputA, [=](OutputB outputB) {
      // ...
      asyncC(outputB, [=](OutputC outputC) {
        // ...
        asyncD(outputC, [=](OutputD outputD) {
          ...;
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

With c++11, is there a way to organise the code above nicely? Thanks a lot!

Comment: oO What is that?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<class T>
struct my_future:std::shared_future<T> {
  using std::shared_future<T>::shared_future;

  template<class F>
  auto operator->*( F f )&&
  -> my_future< std::decay_t<decltype(f(std::declval<T const&>()))> >
  {
    auto self = std::move(*this);
    return std::async( std::launch::async,
      [f, self]() mutable ->decltype(std::declval<F&>()(std::declval<T const&>())){
        return f(self.get());
      }
    );
  }
};
```

Now your `Async` functions return `my_future<Output>`.

You simply chain them with `->*`.

Specialize for `void` ones:

```
template<>
struct my_future<void>:std::shared_future<void> {
  using std::shared_future<void>::shared_future;

  template<class F>
  auto operator->*( F f )&&
  -> my_future< std::decay_t<decltype(f())> >
  {
    auto self = std::move(*this);
    return std::async( std::launch::async,
      [f, self]() mutable ->decltype(std::declval<F&>()()){
        self.wait();
        return f();
      }
    );
  }
};
```

Test code:

```
my_future<int> f = std::async( []{ return 7; } );
auto f2 = std::move(f)->*[](int x){ return x*2; };
std::cout << f2.get() << '\n';
auto f3 = std::move(f2)->*[](int y){}->*[]{ return 42; };
std::cout << f3.get() << '\n';
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00a2d7969666d9f8).

Basically this is implementing a `.then` and using `future`s.

Your code becomes:

```
fooAsync(input)
->*[=](Output output) {
  // ...
  return asyncA(output);
}
->*[=](OutputA outputA) {
  // ...
  return asyncB(outputA);
}
->*[=](OutputB outputB) {
  // ...
  return asyncC(outputB);
}
->*[=](OutputC outputC) {
  // ...
  return asyncD(outputC);
}
->*[=](OutputD outputD) {
  ...;
};
```

Note that intermediate values can be generated, stored, passed around, and processed elsewhere.

Also note that futures can be augmented to launch fewer threads.

Imagine your augmented future has an *optional* "continuation" (that returns void) wrapped carefully in a mutex.

The following is pseudo-code:

```
template<class T>
struct future_state {
  mutable std::mutex m;
  std::condition_variable cv;
  std::optional<T> value;
  std::function<void(T&&)> continuation;

  void set_value( T&& t ) {
    {
      auto l = lock();
      if (continuation)
        return continuation( std::forward<T>(t) );
      value.emplace( std::forward<T>(t) );
    }
    cv.notify_one();
  }
  bool has_value() const {
    auto l = lock();
    return (bool) value;
  }
  bool has_continuation() const {
    auto l = lock();
    return (bool) continuation;
  }
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock() const {
    return std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m);
  }
  T get_value() const { 
    auto l = lock();
    cv.wait( l, [&]{ return (bool)value; } );
    T r  = std::move(*value);
    value = std::nullopt;
    return r;
  }
  // etc
};

template<>
struct future_state<void> {
  // TODO
```

now wrap a `std::shared_future` like interface around a `shared_ptr<future_state>` with a `.then` or `->*` method that either attaches a continuation (if the old one isn't finished) or launches a new thread with the new effort (if the old one is finished), and returns the resulting future-like.

Now your async code may prefer to manage its own threading/async-ness.  A "sync continuation" that doesn't launch a new thread if the task is already ready works reasonably well, and attaches a continuation to the future state if it isn't ready.

None of this is easy; it is threading code.  Looking into the implementation of `.then` for `std::future` may be enlightening.

Comment: amazing piece of code! I'm specifically looking for similar paradigm to make complex nested state/sub-state logic. Could you please elaborate! Is there any examples of opensource production code that uses your approach? I'm struggling to understand it? How can we make it compatible with thread pool system (async is spawning a new thread now, each time its not so efficient and I need a guaranteed "main thread" queue for UI work)

Comment: @barney this is heavily based on my understanding of the new concurrency futures in C++2?.  For a more complete and correct variant, track down the TS with the new futures in them and mimic them.  There ia (last I checked) even the concept of executors on continuations (where by default futures go back to their excutor to schedule a continuation mayhap?)

Comment: btw your first code (my_future) doesn't compile in "auto operator->*( F f )&& -> my_future < std::decay_t < decltype(F&(T const&))> >" Expected a type & F doesn't refer to a value

Comment: @barney Possibly fixed.

Comment: declval helped, but now problem in lambda [f, self]() mutable ->decltype(F&(T)) .. - "F doesn't refer to a value". As far as I understand decltype requires an expression / value not a type, right? And "F&(T)" is supposed to be a type of function taking T and returning reference to F, right? I just cannot understand how tu use declval here to declare a && ref to this type to fix the error)

Comment: @barney Live example added with typos fixed.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. Can you please elaborate on the syntax. What does "operator-> * ( F f )&& -> ..." mean? What kind of syntax is it, to use  && after the function parameters, but before the trailing return type? 2) "auto self = std::move(*this);" is a mystery to me. How it works? We dereference self so we take its value and cast it to an rvalue, then assign to "self" (using move constructor, that would rip off its guts). Does it mean that current ivars inside operator -> *'s this instance would become invalidated now?? Why this code is valid?

Comment: 3) "using std::shared_future<void>::shared_future;" is this just a way to inherit a constructor? I don't get how it works ) 4) what is the value of "f" and how does this operator ->* work on rvalue (move(f)) anyway? %)